# Why is there a pip and pip3 on my windows 10 when both point to the same Python 3.8.1 installation?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I only installed Python 3.8.1 on my Windows 10, from some instructions I started to use pip3 and installed all the requirements with pip3 but I was hit with numerous problems, especially the packages I just installed can't get imported by python error. Then I did this `pip3 --version` and `pip --version`, the results are different. Then I did `pip --list` and `pip3 --list`, the results are different too, of course, so I did all the requirements in pip, and that seems to fix my problem.

So now I have this question, why is there a pip and then a pip3 on the same Python 3.8.1?

`where pip` and `where pip3` both return the same folder, `C:\Python38\Scripts\pip3.exe`

Comment: Which versions? If you have both Python2 and Python3 installed, they may be pointing to different Python versions. You can find each one's location with `where pip` and `where pip3`

Comment: You *shouldn't* have any problems if you target Python 3 though. Perhaps the *real* error is targeting Python 2 instead of Python 3. `I was hit with numerous problems, especially the packages I just installed can't get imported by python error.` What problems, what packages? Python 2 is EOL so the real fix should be to *not* use it

Comment: I only installed one version, the latest release `Python 3.8.1`. And it's on `Windows 10`. What I want to know is why python will have two separated sets of scripts corresponding to two different pip version which is on the same location after all.

Comment: Are they? What did `where pip` and `where pip3` return? How do you create and run *your code*? What instructions did you follow? What is the *actual* error?

Comment: both return the same folder, C:\Python38\Scripts\pip3.exe

Comment: In that case, there's no pip mixup issue. You probably tried to use Python 2 instructions and got errors when you tried to install Python2-specific pacakges. You *still* haven't explained what you did, what instructions you followed. You didn't even post any error messages

Comment: Please post what you actually did so people can reproduce and investigate the problem. After 2 days there's no usable information in the question

Comment: I'm using the ninja based build system, and the only error message is a lot import errors when I tried to use cmake build, while I'm positive that ninja is properly installed on my Windows system. Then I found that I used pip3 instead of pip to install the packages, and use pip to install the required packages again seemed to helped my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Binaries like python and pip point to the default version of Python which was often 2.x, and pip3 and python3 point to the latest installed version of Python 3.x. This was necessary because a lot of software was written for Python 2 and not updated to work with py3. Now that python 2 has reached its end of life, this should hopefully go away in the future.